# Laravel login form is not working for users created by admin

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and using laravel auth to register and login users. Its working good.

**Problem:** I'm creating users from admin panel as well. But the users created from admin panel are unable to login.

Login Form is same for both form (frontend register form and admin panel user registration form). and that login form works well for users who registered using frontend form not for other.

I'm encrypting the user password in bcrypt(123456) also I've tried Hash::make(123456).

Database table is same for both users (created from frontend and created from admin panel).

```
 $user = new User();
 $user->name              = $request->input('name');
 $user->email             = $request->input('email');
 $user->password          = bcrypt(123456);
 $user->save();
```

Error I'm getting on login: These credentials do no match our record

What I should do ?

[image: Stored record in db:]

Comment: Show your login code.

Comment: Try to use `\Hash::make('123456')` for the password

Comment: I'm using the default laravel login. I haven't modified that

Comment: @Nerea I've triend that but same issue: "These credentials do not match our records"

Comment: Is the user you are trying to create actually created?

Comment: Show us the new record that has been created in the database.

Comment: Yes @IvankaTodorova I've attached screenshot. Do have a look

Comment: Did you use softdeletes?

Comment: No I'm not using softdeletes

Comment: What are the field names in the screenshot above? What is the NULL field?

Comment: NULL field is address field

Comment: If you are using default laravel auth  it check the email and password, not the username, so are you login with email?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I've tried that with string as well but no vain

Comment: @Nerea yes I'm login with email

Comment: @Nerea Sorry, but default auth has not address and images. Did you change something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using this on the Controller you can follow Laravel Hashing documentation:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UpdatePasswordController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Update the password for the user.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        // Validate the new password length...

        $request->user()->fill([
            'password' => Hash::make($request->newPassword)
        ])->save();
    }
}
```

Pay attention to this after the namespace `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;` and if you want to hardcode the password replace `Hash::make($request->newPassword)` with `Hash::make('password')`

Here the link [Hashing Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/hashing)

Answer (score 0):

```
User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
```

Try it )

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my problem. Auth automatically bcrypt() password fields... You don't need to bycrpt it when you're saving a user.

Comment: Auth does not automatically hash anything. The RegisterController explicitly hashes the password in the `create` method. https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php#L68

Comment: @lagbox Check out the password field its storing the password in hash in database. I haven't bcrypt() this password. http://prntscr.com/f0x67j